# How to find tweets that contain a URL?

Tags: twitter

Is there a possibility to search for tweets which link to a specific URL or, even better,  domain?

There is already a service doing this, but I can't figure out how to do it myself via the twitter-Api...

http://backtweets.com/api

It seems rather impossible to just collect all tweets which include a URL, expand the URL,  save them all and just then look for certain URLs..

Comment: Use search api, with your link in request.

Comment: Or you can use `url:"google com"` (with dots replaced with a space), for example, it's used [in this code](https://github.com/medialab/gazouilloire/blob/2f6131b067cee0fad38db531761e83e1694d6149/gazouilloire/run.py#L353)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

New solution:

You can use the api method [get-tweet-search](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) from Twitters api. To find tweets containing an url you have to pass the parameter `q="url:stackoverflow.com"`. Unfortunately you must have an access token to do this call.

More info how to use Twitters search operators can be found at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators.

---

This answer is now soon 8 years old. Twitter have changed their api since.

*Old answer:*

Hope this might be to any help.

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=<query>
You can use .atom (xml) and .json. Just remeber to url-encode the string.

Example:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=stackoverflow.com
```

Read the [Documentation Here](http://search.twitter.com/api/)

Comment: ahh, I see why my previous tries did not return any results, because the tweets of my company containing the URL in question were already more than four days old and are currently not taken into consideration when submitting a search. Thanks a lot for the quick answers, then it works as hoped.

Comment: Is it possible to search all urls' ? I mean, i won't search a specific url, i want to list all tweets which has any URL.

Comment: @Eray Yes, by using filter:link search operator!

Comment: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68 (naturally this link is dead lol…) New URL is https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json

Comment: I can't get this to work (bad auth) but this works https://twitter.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com

Comment: For future visitors: this method is deprecated.

Answer (score -2):

Why dont you use `site:"google.com"` keyword. It returns the tweets that has at least one url on google.com domain link with your other constraint.