# how can I retrieve tweets with URLs from a user's stream?

Tags: php, twitter

I have oAuth in place using Jaisen Mathai Epi PHP library.

How can I retrieve tweets with URLs from a user's stream ? (capped by 300 tweets) ?

I am very new to this and found out that search api only yields last 5 days results, so I can't use the search api anymore.

how can I retrieve such filtered data ?

Comment: I don't believe you can retrieve a filtered list of tweets from a user via the twitter API. Your best bet is probably to retrieve all tweets and then do the filtering in PHP (you can use regex to check if a post has a URL in its message)

Comment: @MrGlass I was looking into retrieving these tweets(300). I'm so confused between Streaming vs REST API (timeline calls). Which one do you recommend ?

Comment: I haven't worked their api in a while but i interacted with both before. Streaming is great if you want to listen for occurances of something, and trigger a response. It isn't easy to implement though. It sounds like you want historical data (EG what the user has already tweeted) and for that you need to use REST

Comment: @MrGlass is correct. Please see here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/21869/15489

Comment: Please see this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3584482/109941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use Regex and you don't have to use the streaming API. Twitter has built in methods in it's [REST api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) to handle the issue.

to capture the Tweet URL's in your search:

Add the parameter `include_entities=1` to the end of your API call.

[Tweet entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities)

You will get back an extended JSON with the expanded and short URL versions and their positions in the tweet.

```
"urls": [
        {
          "url": "http://t.co/0JG5Mcq",
          "display_url": "blog.twitter.com/2011/05/twitte…",
          "expanded_url": "http://blog.twitter.com/2011/05/twitter-for-mac-update.html",
          "indices": [
            84,
            103
          ]
        }
      ],
```

The cap limit on the Twitter API is 100 tweets and 10 days. On some calls it's 20 tweets. What you will want to do is use an API that circumvents the search limit. Snapbird is the most popular solution for this.

[Snapbird API](https://github.com/remy/snapbird)

Comment: Will this return ONLY the tweets that contain URLs?

Comment: No, if you want to capture the tweets that only have URLS in them then you will need to use the streaming API, but as mentioned above. You wont be able to capture historical data and it's a lot harder to implement. All though, if your working from the ground up you can look at the [140 dev server](http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-blog/category/140dev-source-code/) to help with streaming in PHP. What you can do is filter the REST results yourself, taking out the tweets that dont have URL entities and keeping the ones that do.

Comment: -1: This doesn't answer the OP's question. The OP wants tweets *only* from a user's stream. Please see here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/21869/15489

Comment: @JimG, your downvoting my answer to direct users to an irrelevant post you made on WebApps?? What are you talking about frankly? If you want a users own stream all you need to do is include the entities parameter to a user stream API call. It's supported.. `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json?include_entities=true` why would anyone need to use Twitter search? That's been noted as being completely unreliable. Just use the REST api, no need to hack around with it. And for that matter use Fiddler to try to find and use the Phoenix search URL, that will take you down a bad path.